# updating active record does not update a field with an array...why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have a model where there is a username string and a string array of interests. What I'd like to do is to allow the user to add interests when they click a button by appending their interest to the current array. However when I `update` it doesn't update the array field in the model. Why is that?

For example if you are in rails console...

```
@existing = User.find(1)
ints = @existing.interests
ints.append("a new interest")
@existing.update(interests: ints)
```

This does not update the record and I can't figure out why...I see in my database it says Begin, Commit, True but when I do `User.find(1)` it only shows the array without the new interest added.

here's the schema:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
   t.string   "email"
   t.string   "interests", default: [], array: true
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

here's the migration

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :interests, array: true, default: '{}'

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Using rails 4+ and ruby 2+ and PSQL

Answer (score 0):

The reason your update fails is because [`ActiveModel::Relation#update`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update) is used improperly. It expects the id of the model you want to update, then the hash of attribute. You want to use `Model#update_attributes` or `Model#update_attribute`:

```
@existing.update_attributes(interests: ints) # Takes a hash of attributes
# or
@existing.update_attribute(:interests, ints) # takes the name of the column, and the new value
```

Things to be aware of with Arrays: the ActiveRecord dirty tracking does not track in place updates, only the setter tracks dirty state.

There are 2 options to solve this:

1. Call `<attribute>_will_change!` will mark the attribute as dirty
2. Use `model.attribute += [new_object]` to append in an assignment, marking it dirty

Comment: `@existing.update_attribute(:interests, ints)` gives me a wrong number of arguments error and `@existing.update_attributes(interests: ints)` still doesn't save to the database. I don't know what you mean by `<attribute>_will_change!` or `model.attribute +=[new_object]` can you clarify that? Specifically I don't understand `the ActiveRecord dirty tracking does not track in place updates, only the setter tracks dirty state.` If you have some documentation that I can read that would be much appreciated.